# Can I use instaloader with proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, instagram, instagram-api, instaloader

so the issue is that I can't access instagram from my region, and I need to use either VPN or proxy.
And my simple program doesn't work. So is there a way I can use proxy with instaloader? Thanks.

```
import instaloader
 
# Creating an instance of the Instaloader class
bot = instaloader.Instaloader()
 
# Loading the profile from an Instagram handle
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, 'cristiano')
print(profile)
```